# nginx looking for staticfiles in the wrong place

Tags: django, nginx

my Django deployment with ec2, nginx and gunicorn went well beside that my staticfiles are not loading, browser show a 404 error. And this is because nginx looks in a completely different place than statics.
At this point I have tried a lot of configurations and nothing does the trick. I am wondering if a pair of fresh eyes can spot a mistake here that I do not.

/sites-enabled/django.conf:

```
server {
    server_name  site.net www.site.net;

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/ubuntu/saas/static/;
}

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/saas/app.sock;
}

    location ~ \.css {
        add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
}
    location ~ \.js {
        add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
}

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}



server {
    if ($host = www.site.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = site.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



    listen 80;
    server_name  site.net www.site.net;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

and my django settings.py look like this and collectstatics works fine.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

I have deleted the default file but it stills seems that nginx looks for the staticfiles in the wrong place according to this error.log:

```
2020/05/01 19:57:45 [error] 3502#3502: *6 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/css/custom.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 86.221.78.105, server: site.net, request: "GET /static/cs$
```

I have rebooted the server, reload nginx, nothing seems to work out. Would someone has an idea of what I could try at that point?

Comment: Did you remember to run `python3 manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: yes and it works fine. the folder has everything it needs in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to resolve the problem. Getting rid of the default index.html in /usr/share/nginx/html/ and running the conf script as:

```
server {
    server_name  site.net www.site.net;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/ubuntu/saas/static/;
}

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/saas/app.sock;
}

}



server {
    if ($host = www.site.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = site.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



    listen 80;
    server_name  site.net www.site.net;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

Although this seems to be a workaround it makes the trick
```

Answer (score 0):

There's usually a `default.conf` file that gets installed with `nginx` when you install with `yum` or `apt`.  It will either be in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` or `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf`.  Delete that file and reload `nginx` with `sudo systemctl reload nginx`, and you should be good to go absent there being another configuration file on your server that you don't know about.

Comment: i did that, but before i deleted i saw somewhere to add locations with css and js. I deleted index.html and those two locations and it seems to work